# getting com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.client.index.FtFeederException: in Documentum Index Agent

Tags: indexing, documentum

I just did brought Index Agents and Explore Server down and started Explorer server again.

Now when I am trying to bring Index Agent up using "Start Index Agent in Normal Mode" option, I am getting the following error:

com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.client.index.FtFeederException: Error while getting the customization class name for routing to a collection. Host [*******************] and Port [****]

[image]

Do I need to check anything  else as well?